# Зачем нужно ключевое слово yield в __iter__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, итераторы, yield

Зачем в методе `__iter__` используют ключевое слово `yield`?

```
def __iter__(self):
    for page_number in self.page_range:
        yield self.page(page_number)
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из документации по [__iter__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#container.__iter__):

> Метод `container.__iter__` возвращает объект [итератор](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator).

Любая функция в теле которой упоминается [yield](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) становится [генератором](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#index-19). Вызов такой функции не приводит к исполнению кода внутри (!), возвращается [generator iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator) и всё. Чтобы начать её исполнение надо результат вызова передать в функцию [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

Пример:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.page_range = range(10)

    def page(self, n):
        return f'page {n}'

    def __iter__(self):
        for page_number in self.page_range:
            yield self.page(page_number)


c = C()
# неявный вызов c.__iter__()
it = iter(c)
print(it)
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
```

> ```
> $ python c.py
> <generator object C.__iter__ at 0x7f00dcb54200>
> page 0
> page 1
> page 2
> ```

Вся машинерия связанная с `iter`/`next` обычно спрятана в цикл `for`:

```
c = C()
for p in c:
    print(p)
```

> ```
> page 0
> page 1
> page 2
> page 3
> page 4
> page 5
> page 6
> page 7
> page 8
> page 9
> ```

Ваш пример можно переписать без `yield`. Теперь это нормальная функция, у неё необычный результат - выражение-генератор:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return (self.page(page_number) for page_number in self.page_range)
```

Или так:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return map(self.page, self.page_range)
```